# Switching a PMT from PC-mode to DC-mode: What happens?

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy

I was wondering a bit how it is possible to switch a photo multiplier tube from the photon counting mode to the DC (I assume direct current)-mode. If I simply add a high voltage (as usual), I get the dark signals out (measured with an oscilloscope). When I let more photons get in, I get more counts. But I know, too, that every PMT has a mode where the resulting current increases linearly to the incoming photons, called DC-mode. So, I was wondering now if I simply have to increase the amount of photons going into the PMT (seems strange, because then I only get more and more counts), or if there has to be changed something else, too. Can someone help me if possible?

Comment: have you actually observed what happens when you increase the photon rate (be careful to stay within the limits of your PMT) ? If you have a high rate, pulses from individual photons will 'overlap' and look like a steady current (as illustrated e.g. here: http://www.vertilon.com/pmt_readout.html )

Comment: When I increase the photon rate, the photo current rises, but when the rate stays constant, the rate drops down to zero, so I assume that the values I get are the derivative of the real values...

Comment: sounds like something cuts off the DC component in your signal. Just a thought: does your PMT amplifier support DC mode ? (can you share which model it is ?)

Comment: My PMT is a C31034A, and my display device is an oscilloscope, but maybe I used the wrong settings there...

Comment: what is the 'coupling' setting at the scope input ?

Comment: It was set to AC, I think that was the reason, switched it to DC

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking through a PMT manual (One suggestions is [Hamamatsu](https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/etd/PMT_handbook_v3aE.pdf)).  The only real difference is the readout circuit (and worries about linearity).  In DC mode it is assumed that there are lots of photons coming in, so that the output current is roughly constant and you are measuring average intensity.  This means something like a few photons per response time...